# Simplifying exponentials of the form $\,a^x \cdot b^y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

I am given the exponential $\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^x\cdot 4^{(x/2)}$. While my intuition screams that this can be simplified to $\dfrac{2^x}{2^x} = 1$, I am unable to see a concrete mathematical explanation for this.

Comment: $4^y = (2^2)^y = 2^{2y}$, and $(1/2)^z = (2^{-1})^z = 2^{-z}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, we have the form $a^x\cdot b^y$, with the added knowledge that $y = \frac 12 x$.

So we can manipulate the expression to obtain the product of two bases raised to the same power, as you did, or as shown below. It all falls out from the [laws of exponents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laws_of_exponents#Identities_and_properties), as they relate to real numbers.

$$\left(\dfrac 12\right)^x \cdot 4^{(x/2)} = \left(\dfrac 12\right)^x \cdot 2^{\left(2  (x/2)\right)} = \left(\dfrac 12\right)^x \cdot 2^{x}= \left(\dfrac 12\cdot 2\right)^x = 1^x = 1$$